# PostGIS ST_Buffer Radius

Tags: postgis, postgis-1.5

I am trying to find all points within a five-mile radius of a given point. I have a query like this:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE ST_Contains(ST_Buffer(geomFromText('POINT(0 0)', 4326), ?), latlon)
```

I cannot figure out what I put in place of `?` (radius) to get five miles. Everything is in EPSG 4326, and according to PostGIS documentation (as best as I can tell), my radius should be in meters. If I put in 12,070.0m (approximately 5-miles), I get matches half way across the country. Does anyone know what I am missing?

Comment: 4326 is dd (decimal degrees). 12070 is quite a big area (radius) when it is projected as latlon.

Comment: incorrect - 12 070 meters = 7.49995029 miles so 5 miles is 8046.72 meters so (?=8046.72) - is your data geography or geometry?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Because your data isn't projected - it is points on a spheroid - linear distances sort of don't make sense. Five miles at the equator is a much smaller angle than 5 miles on the arctic circle. But luckily PostGIS (>= 1.5) has the answer you're looking for:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE ST_DWithin(ST_GeogFromText('SRID=4326;POINT(0,0)'),
                 geography(latlon), 12070);
```

It has a `geography` type that is designed for just this sort of thing. It's similar to geometry, but it only ever uses EPSG:4326, and there are far fewer functions that work with it.

In the sample above, I have called [ST_GeogFromText()](http://www.postgis.org/documentation/manual-svn/ST_GeogFromText.html) (There is also a [ST_GeographyFromText()](http://www.postgis.org/documentation/manual-svn/ST_GeographyFromText.html), and I'm not sure if there is a difference) on the point of interest (it might work with regular WKT, because the SRID parameter is redundant), and cast the latlon column to the geography type. If you're doing lots of these, it can be more efficient to create a geography column in your table and skip the cast entirely. Finally, [ST_DWithin()](http://www.postgis.org/documentation/manual-svn/ST_DWithin.html) can take geography parameters, and it does the right thing with linear distances.

Comment: I appreciate the help. I am still fairly new to PostGIS.

Answer (score 4):

perhaps you want the ST_DWithin function instead. see note in the st_buffer doc.
[ST_Buffer](http://www.postgis.org/documentation/manual-1.5/ST_Buffer.html)

> People often make the mistake of using this function to try to do radius searches. Creating a buffer to to a radius search is slow and pointless. Use [ST_DWithin](http://www.postgis.org/documentation/manual-1.5/ST_DWithin.html) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use specific postgis operator <->

```
select *    
from poi_1
CROSS JOIN LATERAL (SELECT poi_2.id poi_2_id
FROM poi_2
WHERE poi_2.status = 'VERIFIED'::text
ORDER BY (poi_1.geometry <-> poi_2.geometry)
LIMIT 1) p2
```