# How do I use st_dwithin with meters?

Tags: postgis

I am trying to follow [PostGIS ST_Buffer Radius Help](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/17305/postgis-st-buffer-radius-help) to use a 50 meter distance but postgis is returning an error.

I am trying the following SQL,

```
SELECT id FROM table 
WHERE ST_DWithin(ST_GeogFromText('SRID=4326;POINT(-3.165356 55.926665)'), 
      geography(geometry), 50);
```

The hints indicated at ST_GeogFromText are,

- function st_geogfromtext(unknown) does not exist at character 92
- No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Any help/alternatives would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

As mentioned in [docs](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html):

> For Geometries: The distance is specified in units defined by the
>   spatial reference system of the geometries.

If your data is in SRID=4326 the distance you are specifying is in radians.

You either have to use [ST_Transform](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_Transform.html) and meter based coordinate system, or one of the two functions: [ST_Distance_Sphere](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_Distance_Sphere.html) (faster, less accurate) or [ST_Distance_Spheroid](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_Distance_Spheroid.html).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I used the functions above and they indeed return meters but i can only use them to calculate a distance between two latlong geometries and I need to use it to calculate distance from polygon edges. I thought of a solution with the above info, I could use st_closestPoint() to my polygon and then st_distance_sphere() which will do the trick. Problem is I am using postgis 1.4 and st_closestPoint() is unavailable. Also, I would like to use minimum code because ST_WDistance() will return a simple true/false whilst the other alternatives need more coding.

Answer (score 6):

You need PostGIS 1.5 or greater to have the geography type. The older versions have the ST_Distance_Spher*() functions, but as you note, they only work for points.