# find all circles intersecting another in a table

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I am using postGreSQL (9.3) and postGIS (2.1).
I have a table containing names and circles (point + radius).

Given a name and a circle (point + radius), I would like to find all the database lines that contains (circles that intersect my circle) AND (share the same name). Is it possible using postGIS ?

Here is what I have so far, taken from [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13869980/how-to-create-a-circle-in-meters-in-postgis) [questions](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/10352/how-to-create-a-circle-in-postgis) on this site.  Please note that I am just beginning to learn postGreSQL :

```
--create table

CREATE TABLE circles (
    city VARCHAR(50),
    geog geography
);

-- insert sample values

INSERT INTO circles (city, geog)
VALUES ('Lannion', geometry(ST_Buffer(geography(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(48.732084 -3.459144)')), 1000)));

INSERT INTO circles (city, geog)
VALUES ('Lannion', geometry(ST_Buffer(geography(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(48.732084 -3.459144)')), 2000)));

INSERT INTO circles (city, geog)
VALUES ('Lannion', geometry(ST_Buffer(geography(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(48.732084 -3.459144)')), 3000)));

INSERT INTO circles (city, geog)
VALUES ('Lannion', geometry(ST_Buffer(geography(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(48.732084 -3.459144)')), 4000)));

INSERT INTO circles (city, geog)
VALUES ('anotherName', geometry(ST_Buffer(geography(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(48.732084 -3.459144)')), 1000))); -- not selected because the name is different

-- search (need help for this one) 
SELECT ST_Buffer(geometry(ST_MakePoint(48.732084, -3.459144)), 2500) FROM circles;
```

I can't make sense of the output of the `SELECT` query so far. Also, it doesn't have any constraint on the city name. I would like to have as output the first two inserts in this case.

Comment: Could you explain in words what your query should look like. ST_Buffer simply expands an existing geometry, it does not find intersections. I think you are looking for ST_Intersects in conjunction with some use of city in the WHERE clause.

Comment: @JohnBarça Yes ST_Intersects is probably what I want. The serach query is more of an attempt, this is why I gave the example result it should return. I should maybe remove my attempt to make the question more clear ?

Comment: I believe what you're after is ST_DWithin() -- it's almost always what should be used when people first think of using st_buffer(). Check out the many questions here regarding ST_DWithin(). E.G. http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/77688/3195; http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/125187/3195; http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/63981/3195; http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/32711/3195

Comment: You mention circles. Are you *sure* you have circular entities, or are you just doing distance based searches?

Comment: Hello @MartinF you are right I am doing distance based searches. Should I use ST_DWithin() ?

Comment: Alright it looks a lot like the link you gave me : http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/77688/postgis-get-the-points-that-are-x-meters-near-another-point-in-meters but your answer does it for two points, how do I adapt it for one point versus all the points in a table ? Sorry if this sounds a stupid question.

Comment: It was set up that way for clarity about st_dwithin. You'll have to do some more thinking/research/experimenting (eg, look at the other example Qs) to make it fit your situation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22712/discussion-between-nha-and-martin-f).

Answer (score 0):

Judging from comments, you are looking for a simple geometry(point) intersects all the geometry on a table right?

What you can use it should be something like this;

```
select * from circles 

where st_intersects (circles.geog,(ST_PointFromText('POINT (48.732084 -3.459144)',4326)))
```

Mind the SRID mixing problem. Because i gave 4326 to the selectiong geometry.

Comment: Thank you I'll try that when I get home :) Can you expand a bit on the SRID thing (or just give a pointer to a good ressource) ?

Comment: No, OP doesn't actually *have* circles, just points and nearby lines. But, yes, do pay attention to CRS (coordinate reference system), referred to in PostGIS via SRID (spatial reference system ID).

Comment: Could you expain to me more specific because my English is not that good. Maybe I misunderstood or something. Maybe a explaining with drawing object will be awesome. So that i'll try help.
What i am saying that the insert sql on top is making those points into a polygon. Actually the circles tables is polygon. Am i right?

Comment: I did change the SRID to 900913 to avoid a `ERROR:  Operation on mixed SRID geometries`. But it always returns all points, and doesn't seem to take into account the distance between circles. It doesn't work in my example for instance.